# How to pass ref via array to forwardRef in typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an example I have created in codepen. The table renders with th, but within my IDE the typescript complains about the type at this line:

```js
<TH handleSort={handleSort} ref={refsTh[ind]}>
```

--- Error   Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type '((instance: HTMLTableHeaderCellElement | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type 'RefObject'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLTableHeaderCellElement | null'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'HTMLTableHeaderCellElement'.

I have made this example work when not passing an array and instead a single ref. The problem seems to be because I am creating useRefs dynamically inside an array. Can anyone please advise? Thanks

example code:
https://codepen.io/inspiraller/pen/OJMRZWQ

```js
// import React from 'react';

// ######################################
type shapeTH = {
  handleSort: () => void,
  children: React.ReactNode // BUG: can't pass children any other way to forwardRef
};

type Ref = HTMLTableHeaderCellElement | null;

const TH = React.forwardRef<Ref, shapeTH>(
  ({children, handleSort}, ref) => (
    <th ref={ref} onClick={handleSort}>
      <span className="thSpan">{children}</span>
    </th>
  )
);

// const TH:React.FC<shapeTH> = ({children, handleSort}) => (
//   <th onClick={handleSort}>
//     <span className="thSpan">{children}</span>
//   </th>
// );

// ##################################################

const App:React.FC = () => {
  const arrTh=['id', 'name', 'colour'];

  type shapeRef = ReturnType<typeof React.useRef>;

  const refsTh: Array<shapeRef> = arrTh.map(() => (
    React.useRef<HTMLTableHeaderCellElement>(null)
  ));
  const handleSort: shapeTH['handleSort'] = () => {};
  return (
    <table className="tableGeneric">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            arrTh.map((item, ind) => (
              <TH handleSort={handleSort} ref={refsTh[ind]}>
                {item}
              </TH>
            ))
          }
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useRef` is a generic, which you know because you wrote `React.useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null)` correctly.  The type of the variable `refOne` would have been inferred as `React.RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>`.

The problem is that you manually assigned a type to `refOne` which is more vague than that.  When you look at the return type of the `useRef` function you don't know what generic type it will be called with, so `type shapeRef = ReturnType<typeof React.useRef>` is `React.MutableRefObject<unknown>` where `unknown` is the type of `ref.current`.

You don't need to manually assign types to variables when their types are known from their value.  This is fine:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const refOne = React.useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null);
  const handleSort = () => { };
  return (<P handleSort={handleSort} ref={refOne}>hello</P>);
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WP5jKw)

For your array example you have the same issue.

```
const refsTh = arrTh.map(() => (
  React.useRef<Ref>(null)
));
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vAVm)

FYI #1: You don't want to call a hook on an array may if the array can change length, but your `App` has a fixed array so it's fine.

FYI #2: You can use `React.PropsWithChildren<P>` to add the `children` prop.  But setting it as regular prop works too.